# How to make a div a link as it transitions in CSS

Tags: html, css, transition, expand

I have a website template I'm working on http://www.travenwest.com/projects/dev2 and I have a problem with the expanding boxes on the left (those are one of my multiple problems, at least). I want them to be links to other webpages, and I was wondering if there was a way to make the whole box a link as it expanded from 250px to 100%. Currently I just have the 'Hey' set in a basic link `<a href="http://google.com>Hey</a>` but as I said, I want the whole box to be a link as it expands. Also, I would prefer to keep it in HTML/CSS as I have absolutely no experience in jQuery, JavaScript etc.
Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the center tag is not supported in HTML5. Use the css instead: "text-align: center"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this at your **CSS**

```
#box a{    
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    line-height: 80px
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/fur5D/1/

Comment: That works for the main part of it, but the other part I want is that as the box expands I want to be able to click any part of it, not just where it originally was.
EDIT: If that's even possible, which it very well may not be without using javascript or something.

Comment: Use `line-height: 80px` if you want to vertical align text

Answer (score 1):

Give your anchor tags the following styles:

```
a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using the `<center>` tag to position your text link.
You should give your boxes a matching `class` such as `.box`
That way you could target them all in your CSS file instead of having to repeat the same CSS for multiple `ID`'s

```
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    border-right: 3px solid #000000;
    transition: width 5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    text-align: center;
}

.box:hover {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
```

Adding `text-align: center;` will centre your link text without the need for extra markup

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that. I'm rather new to HTML and CSS (a week or so now) so I'm feeling like a moron as I realize these different things I could have done, haha.